# (Mobile-Only) To Stick or Not To Stick?

Tags: mobile, navigation

I have a somewhat long landing page: http://POPteam.io/

It takes about 5 swipes to get to the bottom. The content is super important and I don't want it to have any distractions, however part of me feels not showing the menu consistently may be breaking existing user expectations ( especially for return visitors who are ready for commitment ).

Is there a clear direction for this particular use-case?

Comment: [sample of the sticky version](http://cl.ly/image/1E382w120F1P)

Answer (score 1):

The menu is blank for me when i'm not in mobile mode otherwise i get the hamburger.  Anyway - this is a situation where it's ok to not have it always there.  Think about the following: the content of the site - you're not a social media site and your most frequent repeat visitors are going to be your own employees.  That being said, when the repeat visitor comes they probably won't scroll down anyway they'll just use the menu that's already there at the top.

If you were making a site that's sole focus was repeat visits and user engagement i think it's better to keep the options there, but this use case falls outside of it and think aesthetically it also works not having the header sticky.

Comment: Thank J for this. Curios..but why do you think our most frequent visitor would be our OWN employees? When it is meant for anyone's employees.